# Facing problems creating a connection between my oracle database and the php code

Tags: php, oracle, database-connection

Hello i am developing a php web application. Unfortunatly i am not comfortable with Oracle DB.
So i have got a TNS entry of the database. Something like this:

```
DBNAME =
    (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xxxxxxxxxxx.com)(PORT = 1530))
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xxxxxxxxxxx.com)(PORT = 1530))
    (LOAD_BALANCE = yes)
    (FAILOVER = yes)
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = dbname)
      (FAILOVER_MODE =
        (TYPE = SELECT)
        (METHOD = BASIC)
        (RETRIES = 25)
        (DELAY = 5)
      )
    )
  )
```

and i got provided this:

`jdbc:oracle:thin@//xxxxxxxxxxx.com:1530/dbname`

I tried this, but it didnt worked:

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>

<?php
class PDOConnection {
    private $db;

    function _construct(){
    try{
        $server = 'xxxxxxxxxxx.com';
        $username = "xxxxx";
        $password = "xxxxx";
        $service_name = "dbname";
        $sid = '';
        $port = 1530;

        $dbCon ="DBNAME =
        (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xxxxxxxxxxx.com)(PORT = 1530))
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xxxxxxxxxxx.com)(PORT = 1530))
        (LOAD_BALANCE = yes)
        (FAILOVER = yes)
        (CONNECT_DATA =
          (SERVER = DEDICATED)
          (SERVICE_NAME = dbname)
          (FAILOVER_MODE =
            (TYPE = SELECT)
            (METHOD = BASIC)
            (RETRIES = 25)
            (DELAY = 5)
          )
        )
      )";
      $this->db = new PDO("oci:dbname=" . $dbCon."; charset=utf8", $username, $password,[
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
      ]);
      echo "Connected";
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    }
}
$obj = new PDOConnection();
?>
```

I also tried this:

```
<?PHP
$oci_user = "xxxxx";
$oci_psw = "xxxxx";
$oci_sid = "sid";
$db_charset = 'utf-8'
?>
```

I did a lot of research, but i am unable to create the connection with my oracle database.
Can u please help me out.

How to create a connection between my php code and the oracle database.

---

debugging:

dbConn.php file:

```
<?php

class dbConn
{

    private $db;       //The db handle
    public  $num_rows; //Number of rows
    public  $last_id;  //Last insert id
    public  $aff_rows; //Affected rows
    private $stid;     //parsed command

    public function __construct($dbuser, $dbpassword, $db_connection)
    {
        $this->db = oci_connect ($dbuser, $dbpassword, $db_connection);
        if (!$this->db) {
            $e = oci_error();
            trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
        }
    }

    public function close()
    {
        oci_close($this->db);
    }

    public function execute($sql)
    {
        $this->stid = oci_parse ($this->db, $sql);
        $rst = oci_execute ($this->stid);
        $rows=array();
        $this->aff_rows = 0;
        if ($rst){
            $this->aff_rows= oci_fetch_all ($this->stid, $rows);
        }
        oci_free_statement($this->stid);
        return $rows;
    }
}
?>
```

test.php file:

```
<?php include 'dbConn.php'; 
$connstr= "DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xxxxx.com)(PORT = 1530))
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xxxxx.com)(PORT = 1530))
(LOAD_BALANCE = yes)
(FAILOVER = yes)
(CONNECT_DATA =
  (SERVER = DEDICATED)
  (SERVICE_NAME = xxxxx)
  (FAILOVER_MODE =
    (TYPE = SELECT)
    (METHOD = BASIC)
    (RETRIES = 25)
    (DELAY = 5)
  )
)
)";

mydb = new dbConn ($username, $userpassw, $connstr);
?>
```

errors:

```
Warning: Undefined variable $username in test.php on line 19

Warning: Undefined variable $userpassw in test.php on line 19

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in dbConn.php:14 Stack trace: #0 
test.php(19): dbConn->__construct(NULL, NULL, 'DESCRIPTION =\r\n...') #1 {main} thrown in dbConn.php on line 14
```

Comment: What does echo $e->getMessage(); give you in the catch?
Or don't you see anything that indicates it is an error?

Comment: @ErwinMoller the page is empty. There is no output

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with PDO, but I use oc_Oracle like this:
in $db_connection provide your whole TNS entry like this:
PHP page:

```
require 'dbConn.php';
$connstr= "(DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xxxxxxxxxxx.com)(PORT = 1530))
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xxxxxxxxxxx.com)(PORT = 1530))
        (LOAD_BALANCE = yes)
        (FAILOVER = yes)
        (CONNECT_DATA =
          (SERVER = DEDICATED)
          (SERVICE_NAME = dbname)
          (FAILOVER_MODE =
            (TYPE = SELECT)
            (METHOD = BASIC)
            (RETRIES = 25)
            (DELAY = 5)
          )
        )
      )";

$mydb = new dbConn ($username, $userpassw, $connstr);
```

And in dbConn.php:

```
class dbConn
{

    private $db;       //The db handle
    public  $num_rows; //Number of rows
    public  $last_id;  //Last insert id
    public  $aff_rows; //Affected rows
    private $stid;     //parsed command

    public function __construct($dbuser, $dbpassword, $db_connection)
    {
        $this->db = oci_connect ($dbuser, $dbpassword, $db_connection);
        if (!$this->db) {
            $e = oci_error();
            trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
        }
    }

    public function close()
    {
        oci_close($this->db);
    }

    public function execute($sql)
    {
        $this->stid = oci_parse ($this->db, $sql);
        $rst = oci_execute ($this->stid);
        $rows=array();
        $this->aff_rows = 0;
        if ($rst){
            $this->aff_rows= oci_fetch_all ($this->stid, $rows);
        }
        oci_free_statement($this->stid);
        return $rows;
    }
}
```

Comment: so i should create two files? dbConn.php and another file? 
I did this and i get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "=" in test.php on line 20

Comment: line 20 is: mydb = new dbConn ($username, $userpassw, $connstr);

Comment: Ah ... included/requred filename must be string literal, sorry. You can put into two files, it usually makes it more readable. And reuseable.

Comment: what should i change, there is still the same issue

Comment: Please post your whole code or the important parts + error message. I've edited the line require 'dbConn.php'; (previously require dbConn.php;)

Comment: please check, i edited and included the two files. The error message is still the same in line 20

Comment: should it be $mydb instead of mydb ?? @bracko

Comment: also, change to $mydb = new dbConn ($username, $userpassw, $connstr);

Comment: @ bracko so i have new errors right now, i will edit the question and show you

Comment: in which file should i define my credentials

Comment: remember, you have to actually set `code` $username, $userpassw `code` before `code` calling new dbConn ($username, $userpassw, $connstr); `code`

Comment: for the begiing set $userpassw and #username in test.php. But it is wiser to put them into different file and just include it.

Comment: done. now only Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in dbConn.php:14 Stack trace: #0 test.php(22): dbConn->__construct('usrxxx', 'pwdxx', 'DESCRIPTION =\r\n...') #1 {main} thrown in dbConn.php on line 14

Comment: do u have any ideas @bracko

Comment: Well, then lets check if you have OCI extension installed and activated. For more on requirements and install: https://www.php.net/manual/en/oci8.requirements.php. To check your setup, php version and modules etc, create a page with phpinfo() [https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php]

Comment: I have tried this tutorial [How To Configure Oracle on XAMPP for Windows - OCI8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kdWWnPC4xzs) but I am not really getting anywhere and I am still struggling. Could you please help me out. 

i have also tried it on a ubuntuu server. So i cloned my repo and installed php, and `pecl install oci8` but when i try to open the page. I get `Error 500` and `xxx.xx.xxx.x is currently unable to process this request.` 

I would prefer to work on the ubuntuu machine so maybe you have any ideas to fix :) 

@bracko

Comment: Hi, I don't have system available to figure this out. Error 500 indicates that some setting in php.ini is not correct. As I don't manage any system with access to internet, installation from official storages are unknown to me. Maybe try to raise another question to get that fixed and then come back here when you have php up and running .